# Catching ACPI events in C#

Tags: button, try-catch, acpi

I'm trying to write small program in C# to do some tasks after pressing "Vivobook" key on my Asus. Problem is button isn't really part of keyboard, standard keypress doesn't catch anything.
I've read somewhere that this button starts ACPI event. Is there any way to view all ACPI events to find this one and later catch it?
If it isn't possible which language allows to do so? Except asm:P